# Paper checkbox and -webkit-column-count

Tags: css, polymer, dart-polymer

This is something I have been researching for a while already but I am not able to find out what's happening here.

On this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/josfelsal/u4oebyt1/) you can see how there is a list of check boxes that are spread over a div using the css rule -webkit-column-count.

The problem is that the check-mark is hidden for some reason on all the columns but the first one. Do you have any tip to fix this?

Here I attach an small example but please check my jsfiddle for a better descriptive view of the situation. Thanks!

```css
.valueLabel {
  /* height: 24px; */
  padding: 7px 12px;
  width: 400px;
}
.valueLabel paper-checkbox {
  margin-right: 12px;
}
.valueLabel paper-checkbox::shadow #ink[checked] {
  color: #f39200;
}
.valueLabel paper-checkbox::shadow #checkbox.checked {
  border-color: #f39200;
  background-color: #f39200;
  /* Version 0.7 paper-checkbox */
}
/* COLUMNS */

.valuesContainer {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0px 16px;
}
.valuesContainer > #valuesDiv {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-gap: 0px;
}
.valuesContainer > #valuesDiv .valuesGroup {
  display: inline-block;
}
.valuesContainer > #valuesDiv .valuesGroup > span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/* LAYOUT WRAP */

.valuesContainer > core-label {
  width: 30%;
  /* 3 COLUMNS */
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: small;
}
.valuesContainer > #valuesDiv core-label.valueLabel {
  display: inline-flex;
}
/* FIX THAT I USED TO SHOW ALL CHECKS WHEN THEY ARE ON COLUMNS, USED ON PAPER ELEMENTS >= v0.7 */

/* IT DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE */

.valueLabel paper-checkbox::shadow #checkbox.checked #checkmark {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-elements/core-elements.html">
<div class="valuesContainer">
  <div id="valuesDiv">
    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-0">
      <paper-checkbox id="1" checked></paper-checkbox>
      <div>January</div>
    </core-label>

    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-1">
      <paper-checkbox id="2"></paper-checkbox>
      <div>February</div>
    </core-label>

    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-2">
      <paper-checkbox id="3" checked></paper-checkbox>
      <div>March</div>
    </core-label>

    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-3">
      <paper-checkbox id="4" checked></paper-checkbox>
      <div>April</div>
    </core-label>

    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-4">
      <paper-checkbox id="5"></paper-checkbox>
      <div>May</div>
    </core-label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as you see on [**this link**](http://jsfiddle.net/yknLbr9w/) even if you remove all CSS of this post the problem stills the same; so i guess the problem source is inside the `link rel` content;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into a rendering bug.  One way to try to correct this is to force GPU rendering.  There are a few ways to do that, and my favorite is to use `transform:translate3d(0,0,0)`. The issue with that, however, is that the element that needs it (`#checkbox.checked #checkmark`) already has a transform.  You can achieve the same results by setting the backface visibility.  I do that in the demo below with the following rule:

```css
.valueLabel paper-checkbox::shadow #checkbox.checked #checkmark {
   ...
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

#### Demo

```css
.valueLabel {
  /* height: 24px; */
  padding: 7px 12px;
  width: 400px;
}
.valueLabel paper-checkbox {
  margin-right: 12px;
}
.valueLabel paper-checkbox::shadow #ink[checked] {
  color: #f39200;
}
.valueLabel paper-checkbox::shadow #checkbox.checked {
  border-color: #f39200;
  background-color: #f39200;
  /* Version 0.7 paper-checkbox */
}
/* COLUMNS */

.valuesContainer {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0px 16px;
}
.valuesContainer > #valuesDiv {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-gap: 0px;
}
.valuesContainer > #valuesDiv .valuesGroup {
  display: inline-block;
}
.valuesContainer > #valuesDiv .valuesGroup > span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/* LAYOUT WRAP */

.valuesContainer > core-label {
  width: 30%;
  /* 3 COLUMNS */
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: small;
}
.valuesContainer > #valuesDiv core-label.valueLabel {
  display: inline-flex;
}
/* FIX THAT I USED TO SHOW ALL CHECKS WHEN THEY ARE ON COLUMNS, USED ON PAPER ELEMENTS >= v0.7 */

/* IT DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE */

.valueLabel paper-checkbox::shadow #checkbox.checked #checkmark {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-elements/core-elements.html">
<div class="valuesContainer">
  <div id="valuesDiv">
    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-0">
      <paper-checkbox id="1" checked></paper-checkbox>
      <div>January</div>
    </core-label>

    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-1">
      <paper-checkbox id="2"></paper-checkbox>
      <div>February</div>
    </core-label>

    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-2">
      <paper-checkbox id="3" checked></paper-checkbox>
      <div>March</div>
    </core-label>

    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-3">
      <paper-checkbox id="4" checked></paper-checkbox>
      <div>April</div>
    </core-label>

    <core-label class="valueLabel" horizontal="" layout="" id="core-label-4">
      <paper-checkbox id="5"></paper-checkbox>
      <div>May</div>
    </core-label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This made it work like a charm! Thank you very much!

I have another question for you. Why transform:translate3d(0,0,0) is your favourite?

Comment: @JoséJavier It really shouldn't be, but I like how little impact it has on element layout, that it's an easy update if I already have a 2d transform on an element, and that it's so easy to remember.  All very subjective and not really important, but what is important is to know that it's one of several options.  Knowing that you have a couple of different ways to force GPU rendering helps if you find one method would conflict with your current styles.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advices, today I've learned that I can control the GPU rendering using these techniques I am willing to know more about that. Any suggestion?

Again thanks for the help.

Comment: @JoséJavier There's a few tricks associated with CSS animations and rendering.  You might want to take a look at https://davidwalsh.name/translate3d and http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css.  Both of those articles seem to have good information in them.  If you search "force gpu rendering css" in google both those articles show up and you can probably find more info from there.